# Recursive Quotation

Tags: bash, double-quotes

When writing bash scripts is there a third level of recursion for double quotes?
I need to use double quotes since single quotes will read variables literally.

I can do

```
"first level \"second level\""
```

But would like to do something like

```
"first level \"second level \\" third level \\"\""
```

I see why that does not work but I need help with syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the backslash as well.

```
"first level \"second level \\\" third level \\\"\""
```

The first `\\` makes a literal backslash, then `\"` escapes the double quote.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Here-Documents to Reduce Complexity

Please don't do this at all. Instead, if you need an additional level of quoting, consider:

1. Correctly intermixing single and double quotes in a way that minimizes the amount of escaping you need to do.
2. Use a here-document and avoid the whole mess.

I'll cover both, but focus more on the second point, since it's simply easier and less error-prone. For example:

```sh
cat <<-'EOF'
first level "second level 'third level'"
EOF
```

The will avoid interpolation altogether, and correctly prints:

> `first level "second level 'third level'"`

If you're doing something more complex than that, you may want to think about refactoring somewhere else in your code to simplify things. Sometimes complexity is unavoidable, but there's almost always a simpler solution if you take a different approach to the problem.

Comment: My first level is a quoted embedded code block: /usr/bin/expect -c "" After that I have the quotes for the syntax of sending a command with expect: send "cp file1 file2" And the last one is correct syntax for the function I am calling on a remote device inside of the expect statement. So it is not just getting text to print correctly